# What is meant by this code generated by VSCode FlutterReduxGen code extension?

Tags: flutter, dart, redux

I am trying to learn flutter redux architecture. I came across a VScode extension that autogenerates the below code. What does the hashcode part mean?

```
  class LoginState {
            final bool loading;
            final String error;
        
            LoginState(this.loading, this.error);
        
            factory LoginState.initial() => LoginState(false, '');
        
            LoginState copyWith({bool loading, String error}) =>
                LoginState(loading ?? this.loading, error ?? this.error);
        
            @override
            bool operator ==(other) =>
                identical(this, other) ||
                other is LoginState &&
                    runtimeType == other.runtimeType &&
                    loading == other.loading &&
                    error == other.error;
        
            @override
            int get hashCode =>
                super.hashCode ^ runtimeType.hashCode ^ loading.hashCode ^ error.hashCode;
        
            @override
            String toString() => "LoginState { loading: $loading,  error: $error}";
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `hashCode` is a property that all objects in dart have

If two or more objects are equal according to the `==` method, then their hashes should be equal too. If two or more objects are not equal according to the `==` method, then their hashes can be equal or unequal

Hashing is a fundamental concept of computer science.Simply put, `hashCode` returns an integer value, generated by a hashing algorithm which can be used for comparision in case of two objects that are of user defined datatype and not primitive datatypes.

Comment: Can you please explain the control flow of this code? I can't understand how this works.